# All cases when check constraints are executed for each row

Tags: sql-server

When creating a check constraint it will be performed on all rows of a table. Does this happen in another case too?

My check constraint calls a function with SQL inside. This is very slow on large tables.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckUnique(@test NVARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE unique_field = @test)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    RETURN 0
END

ALTER TABLE mytable
    ADD CONSTRAINT CCheckUnique CHECK([dbo].CheckUnique(unique_field) = 0)
```

Comment: Why not just simply use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on that column???

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a function to check if a value is unique, use a `UNIQUE INDEX`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_unique_field ON dbo.mytable(unique_field);
```

Or, alternatively (it's the end of the day and i totally forget to incldue them) use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, and @Marc_s reminded me in the above comment:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTAble 
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_unique_field UNIQUE (unique_field);
```

Scalar functions, especially those that reference tables, are known to perform very poorly. An inline table-value function should be used when you can; but you cannot implement those for a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`. Neither are needed here though.

Comment: I wanted to write my own unique handler, because i forgot to add the unique constraint, and sql server refuses to create unique constraint for that column.

Comment: What do you mean it refuses to @user9691205 ? If you're re getting an error you should be sharing that.